# How would one find a vector when only given parametric equations and a point?

Tags: calculus, vectors

When only given parametric equations and a point, I assume the vector would come from the equations and not the point. So, would one take the first digits from each coordinate to be the vector, or would you have to input a certain value in order to get the vector? For example let's say I was given the parametric equations:

x = 7 - 2t

y = 3 + 5t

z = 8 + 4t

Would <7,3,8> be the vector in this case?

Comment: Welcome to Math S.E.  I would say $(7,3,8)$ is a point on the line, and the line's direction vector is $(2,5,4)$

Comment: The vector $(x,y,z)$ is equal to the vector $(7,3,8)$ plus the vector $ (-2, 5, 4)$ multiplied by $t$.